# Showing the choice of selected checkbox after submitting

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am having some trouble getting the form to submit the choice for some checkboxes.  My checkboxes are setup in a custom css format that I need for the website I am helping work on and I am not sure if that is causing it to not submit my results for it to my test page.  My checkboxes must allow multiple choices.

```css
input[type=checkbox] { 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  position: relative; 
  bottom: 1px; 
}

label { 
  display: block; 
} 

table {
  table-layout : fixed;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  align-items: top;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <label><strong>I recommend this title because...*</strong> </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="choice1" name="Choice" checked/>
     This journal is an essential resource for myself and my colleagues
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="choice2" name="Choice" />
    I refer my students to this journal
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="choice3" name="Choice" />
    I publish/​intend to publish articles within this journal
  </label>
  <label>
    <div class="flex">
      <input type="checkbox" id="choice4" name="Choice" />
      <textarea id="other" placeholder="Other" rows="2" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

I have tried altering the setup using extra labels, divs, and other html tutorials, and researched stack overflow to see if others had similar situations with custom css.  so far has not helped with the current problem without throwing my css setup out of whack.

What I am expecting is:

Choices: I refer my students to this journal
I publish/​intend to publish articles within this journal

What I keep getting:

Choices: on

Comment: "on" is the default value for a checkbox; give your checkboxes unique values. How are you submitting your form? A "standard" form submit will likely return a comma-delimited list of the values that were checked. If you submit with javascript, you'll likely need to iterate over the checkboxes and build your list.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to link the value to the text.  My test page pulls in the value attribute and since I can't link a label to the text without my css going nuts, I am looking for an alternative solution

Comment: I would hardcode your values (keep it simple), but if you must have the text, you could use JS to iterate over your labels and set the value for each checkbox to the text that follows it.

Comment: I would set values as "self", "students", "publish", and "other", respectively.

Comment: Ok how would you hardcode the values than.  I am a novice programmer who is extra help to the University that I am currently employed

Comment: Add the value attribute to each checkbox?

Comment: I did, you mentioned a javascript, how would that work for hardcoding the values

Comment: If you added the value manually, there's no need to use JS.

Comment: thats the problem, it shows "self", "publish", etc when I submit.  Not the text that I need it to show

Comment: Then use the desired text as the values.

Comment: Ok, was trying to keep it clean as possible.  What about my textarea one (choice4), how do I link that value since it requires typing in the textbox

Comment: I would just set the value to "other."

Comment: already did.  No dice just shows up as other and not was written in the box itself

Comment: As expected. But the textarea is part of the form too, so you can handle that when you process it.

Comment: ok I need to insure that what ever I put into the text area is processed with the form and so far I got nothing.  results for that selection is still showing Choices: on

Comment: How are you submitting your form? Do you use Javascript or does it go straight to server?

Comment: Sorry for delay, I am currently using a live server build in for Visual Studio code as a testing source

Comment: That still doesn't answer how you are submitting your form. Regardless, just before submitting, you would need to use javascript to copy their "other" answer in the value of the "other" checkbox. But it would definitely be helpful to see how you are submitting it.

Comment: I am submitting to a test html page that I setup using a live server from Visual Studio code as a "get" action

Comment: Then before you submit, if "other" is checked, use JS to copy the value from the textarea to the value of the checkbox.

Comment: ok how would I approach doing that

Comment: This is not  the place for a step-by-step tutorial; do some searching to learn how to modify form inputs.